# Get both id and count of animals in zoo table sql

Tags: sql, oracle, join

I'm trying to get the id of each animal/bird along with the count of animals/birds into a zoo table:

Zoo table:

| zoo_id | country | zoo_name |
| --- | --- | --- |
| z1 | c1 | zoo1 |
| z2 | c1 | zoo2 |

Animal Table:

| id | animal_name | zoo_id |
| --- | --- | --- |
| an1 | anml_1 | z1 |
| an2 | anml_2 | z2 |
| an3 | anml_3 | z1 |

Birds Table:

| id | bird_name | zoo_id |
| --- | --- | --- |
| b1 | brd_1 | z1 |
| b2 | brd_2 | z2 |
| b3 | brd_3 | z2 |

Output:

| zoo_id | country | animal_id | birds_id | anml_bird_flag |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| z1 | c1 | an1 | brd_1 | 1 |
| z1 | c1 | an3 | brd_1 | 1 |
| z2 | c1 | an2 | b2 | 1 |
| z2 | c1 | an2 | b3 | 1 |

The aim here is to have both animal*id, birdid columns along with a animal bird flag column which takes values 0 & 1, where 1 indicates that the zoo has both animal & bird. 0 indicates that zoo either does not have an animal or bird*

I tried to join zoo, animal & bird table based on zoo id and got first 4 columns, however need help with getting 5th column anml_bird_flag

Answer (score 0):

I do not have PL/SQL to hand to double-check for syntax errors. But the query needs to be something like this:

```
SELECT Z.zoo_id, Z.country, A.id AS animal_id, B.id AS bird_id,
  CASE WHEN A.id IS NOT NULL AND B.id IS NOT NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS anml_bird_flag
FROM Zoo Z
LEFT JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT zoo_id, id FROM Animal) A ON Z.zoo_id = A.zoo_id
LEFT JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT zoo_id, id FROM  Birds) B ON Z.zoo_id = B.zoo_id;
```

A note though, if you have more than 1 animal or 1 bird. You're going to get duplicate rows.

You could always group the ids and create a comma separated list.
Something like,

```
    SELECT Z.zoo_id, Z.country,
      LISTAGG(A.id, ',') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY A.id) AS animal_ids,
      LISTAGG(B.id, ',') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY B.id) AS bird_ids,
      CASE WHEN COUNT(DISTINCT A.id) > 0 AND COUNT(DISTINCT B.id) > 0 
 THEN 1
        ELSE 0
      END AS anml_bird_flag
    FROM
      Zoo Z
    LEFT JOIN Animal A ON Z.zoo_id = A.zoo_id
    LEFT JOIN Birds B ON Z.zoo_id = B.zoo_id
    GROUP BY
      Z.zoo_id,
      Z.country;
```